# How to merge data from object A into object B in Python?

Tags: python, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to figure out if there's a procedural way to merge data from object A to object B without manually setting it up.

For example, I have the following pydantic model which represents results of an API call to The Movie Database:

```py
class PersonScraperReply(BaseModel):
    """Represents a Person Scraper Reply"""

    scraper_name: str
    """Name of the scraper used to scrape this data"""

    local_person_id: int
    """Id of person in local database"""

    local_person_name: str
    """name of person in local database"""

    aliases: Optional[list[str]] = None
    """list of strings that represent the person's aliases obtained from scraper"""

    description: Optional[str] = None
    """String description of the person obtained from scraper"""

    date_of_birth: Optional[date] = None
    """Date of birth of the person obtained from scraper"""

    date_of_death: Optional[date] = None
    """Date the person passed away obtained from scraper"""

    gender: Optional[GenderEnum] = None
    """Gender of the person obtained from scraper"""

    homepage: Optional[str] = None
    """Person's official homepage obtained from scraper"""

    place_of_birth: Optional[str] = None
    """Location where the person wsa born obtained from scraper"""

    profile_image_url: Optional[str] = None
    """Url for person's profile image obtained from scraper"""

    additional_images: Optional[list[str]] = None
    """List of urls for additional images for the person obtained from scraper"""

    scrape_status: ScrapeStatus
    """status of scraping. Success or failure"""
```

I also have this SQLAlchemy class that represents a person in my database:

```py
class PersonInDatabase(Base):

    id: int
    """Person Id"""

    name: str
    """Person Name"""
    
    description: str = Column(String)
    """Description of the person"""

    gender: GenderEnum = Column(Enum(GenderEnum), nullable=False, default=GenderEnum.unspecified)
    """Person's gender, 0=unspecified, 1=male, 2=female, 3=non-binary"""

    tmdb_id: int = Column(Integer)
    """Tmdb id"""

    imdb_id: str = Column(String)
    """IMDB id, in the format of nn[alphanumeric id]"""

    place_of_birth: str = Column(String)
    """Place of person's birth"""

    # dates
    date_of_birth: DateTime = Column(DateTime)
    """Date the person was born"""

    date_of_death: DateTime = Column(DateTime)
    """Date the person passed away"""

    date_last_person_scrape: DateTime = Column(DateTime)
    """Date last time the person was scraped"""
```

My goal is to merge the data I received from the API call to the database object. When I say merge I mean assign fields that exist in both objects and do nothing with the rest. Something along the lines of:

```py
person_scrape_reply = PersonScraperReply()
person_in_db = PersonInDatabase()


for field_in_API_name, field_in_API_value in person_scrape_reply.fields: #for field in API response
    if field_in_API_name in person_in_db.field_names and field_in_API_value is not None: #if field exists in PersonInDatabase and the value is not none
        person_in_db.fields[field_in_API_name] = field_in_API_value #assign API response value to field in database class.
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method @Daniel suggested (Using `attrs`) resulted in an error for me, I'm sure it works with regular classes but it results in errors with both SQLAlchemy and Pydantic classes.

After sitting around with the debugger, I saw that both Pydantic and SQLAchemy provide a method to access their field names in string format. In SQLAchemy it's `inspect([SQLALCHEMY MAPPED CLASS]).attrs.key` and Pydantic just has a built in `dict()` method. Kind of silly of me to forget about it when a large selling point of pydantic is that it can serialize data classes to JSON.

Anyway, with those two methods, this is what worked for me:

```py
def assing_empty(person_to_assign: Person, scrape_result: PersonScraperReply):
    blacklisted_fields = ["aliases"] #fields to ignore
    person_to_assign_fields = [x.key for x in inspect(person_to_assign).attrs] #SQLAlchemy fields
    scrape_result_fields = [x for x in scrape_result.dict().keys() if x not in blacklisted_fields] #Pydantic fields

    for field_name in scrape_result_fields:
        if field_name in person_to_assign_fields:
            person_to_assign_value = getattr(person_to_assign, field_name)
            scrape_result_value = getattr(scrape_result, field_name)

            if scrape_result_value is not None and person_to_assign_value is None:
                setattr(person_to_assign, field_name, scrape_result_value)
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `attrs` package.

```
from attrs import define, asdict

@define
class PersonScraperReply(BaseModel):
    """Represents a Person Scraper Reply"""

    scraper_name: str
    """Name of the scraper used to scrape this data"""

    local_person_id: int
    """Id of person in local database"""

    local_person_name: str
    """name of person in local database"""

    aliases: Optional[list[str]] = None
    """list of strings that represent the person's aliases obtained from scraper"""

    description: Optional[str] = None
    """String description of the person obtained from scraper"""

    date_of_birth: Optional[date] = None
    """Date of birth of the person obtained from scraper"""

    date_of_death: Optional[date] = None
    """Date the person passed away obtained from scraper"""

    gender: Optional[GenderEnum] = None
    """Gender of the person obtained from scraper"""

    homepage: Optional[str] = None
    """Person's official homepage obtained from scraper"""

    place_of_birth: Optional[str] = None
    """Location where the person wsa born obtained from scraper"""

    profile_image_url: Optional[str] = None
    """Url for person's profile image obtained from scraper"""

    additional_images: Optional[list[str]] = None
    """List of urls for additional images for the person obtained from scraper"""

    scrape_status: ScrapeStatus
    """status of scraping. Success or failure"""

@define
class PersonInDatabase(Base):

    id: int
    """Person Id"""

    name: str
    """Person Name"""
    
    description: str = Column(String)
    """Description of the person"""

    gender: GenderEnum = Column(Enum(GenderEnum), nullable=False, default=GenderEnum.unspecified)
    """Person's gender, 0=unspecified, 1=male, 2=female, 3=non-binary"""

    tmdb_id: int = Column(Integer)
    """Tmdb id"""

    imdb_id: str = Column(String)
    """IMDB id, in the format of nn[alphanumeric id]"""

    place_of_birth: str = Column(String)
    """Place of person's birth"""

    # dates
    date_of_birth: DateTime = Column(DateTime)
    """Date the person was born"""

    date_of_death: DateTime = Column(DateTime)
    """Date the person passed away"""

    date_last_person_scrape: DateTime = Column(DateTime)
    """Date last time the person was scraped"""


person_scrape_reply = PersonScraperReply()
person_in_db = PersonInDatabase()
scrape_asdict = asdict(person_scrape_reply)
db_asdict = asdict(person_in_db)

for field_in_API_name, field_in_API_value in scrape_asdict.items(): #for field in API response
    if field_in_API_name in db_asdict.keys() and field_in_API_value is not None: #if field exists in PersonInDatabase and the value is not none
        setattr(person_in_db, field_in_API_name, field_in_API_value) #assign API response value to field in database class.
```

Comment: This sounds good and exactly what I need, sadly it doesn't play well with SQLAlchemy. When I decorate the db class with `@define` I get ` assert manager.registry is None
AssertionError`

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer below, Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 after I saw your first comment I tried to find something compatible with sqlalchemy and found some interesting packages, though I wanted to make sure it would work for you, so I didn't edit my answer, but I'm glad I helped to find the solution :)